# Combine folder contents to PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'd like to take a folder and combine all content into one PowerPoint slideshow by use of only the pathname to the folder.  I don't know if this is even possible.

The content of the folder would be multiple other PowerPoint presentation with designators to identify the order (01 - 11, etc.).  The source formatting would need to be maintained.

Any input would be appreciated.

I know i can load a single PowerPoint and insert another file, but when you start working with many files, it becomes quite the task.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.  You'll need to use Dir repeatedly to get the names of the files in the folder and store them in an array.  Sort the array to make sure they're in the right order, then use something like this once for each file in the array to insert the slides:

```
Dim oPres As Presentation
Dim oPresTemp As Presentation
Dim x As Long
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oTmpRng As SlideRange

Set oPres = ActivePresentation
Set oPresTemp = Presentations.Open("C:\SR\CurrentProjects\Client\GetMyGraphic\FUNNEL\Funnel_0032.pptx")

For x = 1 To oPresTemp.Slides.Count
    oPresTemp.Slides(x).Copy
    Set oTmpRng = oPres.Slides.Paste
    Set oSl = oTmpRng(1)
    oSl.Design = oPresTemp.Slides(x).Design
Next

oPresTemp.Close
```

There's a bit more to it than that, but it's a start.  I'd also read through the code here for further ideas:  http://skp.mvps.org/pptxp001.htm